# How to take the correct value if values are duplicated in oracle query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle

I have a table named `TestTable` which contains the following data

```
slno   TESTNAME    STATE

1.  Rahul       100
2.  Ravi        100
3.  Rahul       90
4.  sasi        100
5.  Peter       100
6.  Kiran       90
```

My aim is if `TESTNAME` is duplicated,then i have to take `TESTNAME` which is having `STATE =100` , so here `Rahul       100`

Expected result is as follows

```
slno   TESTNAME    STATE

1.  Rahul       100
2.  Ravi        100
4.  sasi        100
5.  Peter       100
6.  Kiran       90
```

i used following query but no luck

```
select TESTNAME,STATE from TestTable order by slno,to_number(STATE).
```

Do i need to take all the values in to datatable and proccess in c# or we can manage in oracle query?

Comment: Why do you expect Rahul to return 100 instead of 90?

Comment: Why would Rahul have 2 entries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `union all`.

```
select slno,TESTNAME,STATE 
from TestTable 
where state=100
union all
select slno,TESTNAME,STATE 
from TestTable 
where state<>100
and not exists (select 1 
                from TestTable 
                where testname=t.testname and state=100
               )
```

or using `row_number` with custom `order by` condition, prioritizing state=100 row in case there are multiple rows for a testname.

```
select slno,testname,state
from (select t.*,row_number() over(partition by testname order by case when state=100 then 1 else 2 end) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: If it is a single value, then STATE '90' should also come

Comment: it would be returned by these queries.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `Group By` (I assume `State` being `number`)?

```
  select TestName,
         Max(State) as State
group by TestName
```

Comment: he want slno also. In this case your query wont return expected result

Comment: @Gaj: Agree, I've only tried to amend the attempt `select TESTNAME,STATE from TestTable ...`